# Counting Duplicates in python. Why should we take only set and not list or dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, set

```
def duplicate_count(text):
  text = text.upper()
  duplicate_count = 0
  for i in set(text):
      if text.count(i)>1:
          duplicate_count +=1

  return duplicate_count
```

in the for loop why only set is used and not list or dict? In the for loop i in the set(text) will have duplicates right ?

Comment: No, you won't have duplicates, that's the point of using `set`. Have you tried to replace `set` by `dict` or `list`? You will notice that it will not work or give wrong results. That's why `set` is used.

Comment: can you help me out with this statement text.count(i) . Does that mean the values in text counts for every iteration in i and match the similar character/integer ?

Answer (score 1):

Look here.

```
print(set([1,2,2]))
```

gives us `{1,2}`.
Basically in the code, they iterate through the given iterable and for every number they find how many times it is repeated. But say you had [2,2]. Well the number 2 is repeated twice so. We'll go through two twice increasing `duplicateCount` by one TWO times, but we want it to increase it once. So set works the best in this case.

Comment: can you help me out with this statement  text.count(i) . Does that mean the values in text counts for every iteration in i and match the similar character/integer ?

Comment: Yeah so, text is our set. The count function is applied on the [1,2,2]. Say we had text.count(2) it will give us ```2``` because clearlly there are two 2's in the list.

Answer (score 1):

In set all duplicates are removed.

Sets are unordered collections of distinct objects.

The common approach to get a unique collection of items is to use set

for example,

```
l=[1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5]
l1=set(l)
print(l1)
```

here we will get output as

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Sets are generally used to get unique values from lists.

for more details on different ways to remove dupliates from list refer-

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-remove-duplicates-from-list/

Comment: can you help me out with this statement text.count(i) . Does that mean the values in text counts for every iteration in i and match the similar character/integer ?

Comment: text.count(i) counts the occurrence's of 'i' in text and if count is more than 1 which means that there are duplicates the duplicate_count is incremented by 1